# Shell script steps equivalent to windows bat scritp issue

Tags: windows, shell, unix, batch-file

I have shell script(sh) in that below following lines need to write equivalent to windows bat file. Any body help on this

```
**shell script:**

 cd $AUTOMATEDTESTHTTPDIR/../abc/Input
for i in `ls -d *`
do
  cd $i
  cp * ../../def/Unidentified/Requests
  cd ..
done

cd $AUTOMATEDTESTHTTPDIR/../abc/Output

for i in `ls -d *`
do
  cd $i
  cp * ../../def/Unidentified/Responses
  cd ..
done

cd $AUTOMATEDTESTHTTPDIR/../def/Deliver
for d in test1\
         test2\
         test3\
     do
  mkdir $d
  for e in Requests \
           Responses
  do
    mkdir $d/$e
    mv Unidentified/$e/*$d* $d/$e
  done
done
```

How to write above lines in windows bat.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough-cut whack at it. This is -not- tested, but it contains most of what you need to get going. For more information about loops, use `FOR /?` at the cmd shell prompt.

```
CD %AUTOMATEDTESTHTTPDIR%\..\abc\Input
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%i IN (`dir /ad *`) DO (
    CD "%%i"
    COPY * ..\..\dev\Unidentified\Requests
    CD ..
)

CD %AUTOMATEDTESTHTTPDIR%\..\abc\Output
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%i IN (`dir /ad *`) DO (
    CD "%%i"
    COPY * ..\..\dev\Unidentified\Requests
    CD ..
)

CD %AUTOMATEDTESTHTTPDIR%\..\def\Deliver
FOR %%d IN (test1 test2 test3) DO (
    MKDIR "%%d"
    FOR %%e IN (Requests Responses) DO (
        MKDIR "%%d\%%e"
        MOVE "Unidentified\%%e\*%%d*" "%%d\%%e"
    )
)
```